# 100% legal briefcase crack

Tags: steganography

I have recently obtained a locked briefcase by, uhm, completely legal means.

> Stop looking at me like that.

The combination lock has six numbers and I can't seem to figure out the correct combination. There was a small note attached. Maybe it's the owner's favourite poem or something? Seems like near-gibberish to me, though.

> Nine must take gṛeat carẹ w$h$en oṗ$e$ning this box;
> Only th$r$ee shạ$r$p mịnds $i$ts secṛet u$n$locks.
> Have a $g$o aṭ tḥi$s$ rhymẹ,
> Iṇ fact yoụ still have tiṃe.
> Not yet tool one to decode these text ḅlocks.
>
> Tre$a$sure awaiting $b$e two puzzled eyes;
> Having five find $o$ut the tr$u$th from the lies.
> Examine evẹry li$n$e,
> Refactor, ṛe$d$efine,
> Eagerly ṣevening in on the prize.

What I've tried:

> 931-257

Wasn't it... shucks. Out of ideas now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated by Hunter in his answer, there are many red herrings but one true clue:

> the dotted letters read: REPAIR THE NUMBERS

So let's follow that advice and fix the text accordingly:

> <s>Nine</s> **ONE** must take gṛeat carẹ when oṗening this box; 
>  Only <s>three</s> **TWO** (to) shạrp mịnds its secṛet unlocks. 
>  Have a go aṭ tḥis rhymẹ, 
>  Iṇ fact yoụ still have tiṃe. 
>  Not yet tool <s>one</s> **EIGHT** (too late) to decode these text ḅlocks. 
>   
>  Treasure awaiting be <s>two</s> **FOUR** (before) puzzled eyes; 
>  Having <s>five</s> **TWO** (to) find out the truth from the lies. 
>  Examine evẹry line, 
>  Refactor, ṛedefine, 
>  Eagerly <s>ṣeven</s> **ZERO**ing in on the prize.

This gives us the true six-digit code:

> 128420 (thanks to @MOehm for correcting me)

Comment: Very good, but I think that rot13(gbby bar orpbzrf gbby rvtug be gbb yngr naq, creuncf, friravat va orpbzrf mrebvat va).

Comment: @MOehm, I was just going to answer the same thing :)

Comment: Thank you @MOehm, that seems more logical indeed. Fixing my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer

Taking the first letter of each line you find:

> NO HINT HERE (a red herring...)

The letters in *italic* font spell:

> HERRINGS ABOUND (another red herring...)

While taking al the letters with small dots under and over them you read:

> REPAIR THE NUMBERS (maybe a useful hint, this time?)

Still working on it...